# Using third party Email system for Django Password Reset

Tags: python, django, email, passwords, google-compute-engine

I have a Django App hosted on Google Compute Engine(which doesn't allow port 25/465/587 to send Emails). So, I integrated a third party Email system in the Django App. Third party Email system works find on Google Compute Engine too.

But when I use Django Reset Password, that email is still getting sent over by the Django Default Email System. Can this Django Default Email system for password Reset be changed ?

If yes, Can someone please explain how it can be changed ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something like [Email backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/email/#email-backends)

```
# settings.py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'project.backends.mail.CustomEmailBackend'

# project/backends/mail.py
from django.core.mail.backends.base import BaseEmailBackend
class CustomEmailBackend(BaseEmailBackend):
    def send_messages(self, messages):
        for message in messages:
            # do the stuff with each message
            print(message.subject, message.body, message.to, message.cc)
```

Remeber that path dotted in `EMAIL_BACKEND` variable in `settings.py` must be the same as location of your `CustomEmailBackend` class in your project folder tree.

Each `message` has the same [properties](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects).
Of course `send_mail` from `django.core.mail` will work as usuall, but use your `CustomEmailBackend` for sending emails.

Comment: With this code, everything else would remain the same except the email sending by third party ?

Comment: and where this CustomEmailBackend() class be defined ?

Comment: I tried setting EMAIL_BACKEND = 'app.file_name.CustomEmailBackend' in settings.py & added this class in file_name.py file and just added a print() in the for loop... It didn't worked...

Comment: @Naveen did you implement your third party system in place where this comment is : ``# do the stuff with each message``?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122928/discussion-between-turkus-and-naveen).

Comment: this seems to be working. But can you tell how can i receive the other details like to from_email, to_email etc inside this send_message() ? And why a for loop is required ?

Comment: ``message.to``, etc. The rest of properties you'll find here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects loop is required, because to that function you will get a list of messages, of it's one, then list with one item in it.

Comment: I can get the email mesage using message.body  but its in safeText format(which lose its proper format if converted to string). Can I get the Original format of the message back ? (The Original content was in HTML format)

Comment: You have to put html_message first, check: https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/email/#send-mail